# Installing PCI SATA card on older WinXP machine

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation

I have kindof a puzzle here that i can't figure out. 
Firstly, let me apologize if i'm doing this wrong. never used this site before and still figuring out what to do.

First Problem:
One of my older computers cannot seem to hold onto a windowsXP installation for more than 1 mo. WinXP installs fine, however after a period of time, restarting or cold-booting ends up in a situation where i just get a flashing cursor in the upper left corner. I've gone through all the online help i can find to no avail. I can reinstall window fine after a complete format of the drive, however this just places me back into the 1 month or so cycle of formatting and reinstalling windows. Because of this, i began to suspect the drive beginning to fail or the controller failing. So i bought a nifty new PCI SATA controller and new SATA HDD. Which leads me to my second problem:

Problem 2:
The stupid PCI SATA card did not come with a 3.5" floppy and winXP isn't smart enough to use a CD for the drivers. I should have looked a bit closer when i ordered it, i guess.
I now can't figure out how i'm going to get XP on this machine.

I've thought maybe i could get a linux distro that will load from the CD, but don't know what i would do from there to get Win installed.

Then i thought i could get winXP installed using another PC that has an onboard SATA controller. Thinking about this further though, i'm still up the creek with getting it to boot from this drive once i have it installed.

I am now out of ideas. I think i'm probably missing something however i did notice that some SATA controllers come with the 3.5" floppy drivers. perhaps i could return this card for another that would work a bit easier.

I'm open to clever ideas though.

Thank you all for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Please provide details on the card itself. We may be able to track down drivers that will get it installed. You can generally make a driver floppy from the files on the CD as well...

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on the CD of drivers it came with, and somewhere in there will be a folder that contains a file called `oemsetup.inf` - copy all the files inside this folder to a floppy disk, and there's your installation files for the XP installation.

Comment: thanks. i'll give this a shot. now if only i can find a floppy disk that's not gone bad.

Answer (score 1):

Or slipstream the drivers into the XP CD using Nlite

http://www.nliteos.com/nlite.html

.