# Install PCI-E SATA driver on unbootable Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, drivers, sata, pci-express

My SATA controller on motherboard died.

I've pluged a SATA controller on PCI-E. BIOS recognizes it just fine, boots from it, but Windows XP, I assume, lacks drivers for such a controller and reboots. It might be worth noting that the controller on mb was SATA or SATA II, the new one is SATA III.

I really don't want to wipe and reinstall the system, that's a no-go.

What should I do? What will happen if I boot it on another PC with totally different hardware (assuming it will boot)?

Should I hunt for some XP install CD (of course I can't find the original one, this computer is old...)? Will I even be able to install such drivers from the second CD?

Is it even remotely possible to install the drivers from linux level?

I'm a linux guy, so excuse me if I ask trivial/absurd questions.

I've found this question: [Installing PCI SATA card on older WinXP machine](https://superuser.com/questions/189436/installing-pci-sata-card-on-older-winxp-machine) but it gives no feedback, and suggests reinstallation.

The card I've boight is Unitek PCI/PCIE Series Adapter (PCI-E-SATA3-2I2E).

Comment: You might not have a choice.  The adapter requires drivers, so unless you find a way to provide them to Windows, you won't be able to get the installation in a bootable state.You

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking about. How to provide them to Windows :)

Comment: How far into the boot cycle do you get? Does safe mode work?

Comment: No. Every time I get a reboot. If I order from F8 menu not to reboot after a fail, I get a blue screen. Should I provide details on the error? Can't tell how far do I get. When I run safe mode I see drivers loading in the bottom of the screen and it dies.

Comment: You might be able to boot to a CD with recover environment and install the drivers that way? Another thing you might want to confirm is that the new ATA controller is set in the BIOS to IDE emulation instead of AHCI/native. If your old one was set to IDE then changing it can would driver problems.

Comment: That's a good idea, but my bios does not provide such option...

Answer (score 0):

There is no supported method of adding drivers to an install that won't boot.  Seeing as how XP finally reaches end of life next month, you need to install a new version of windows anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the drivers for that new SATA controller onto a floppy to use with Windows XP's Setup F6 driver functionality.

Once you have that:

Boot from your XP disk and do an in-place reinstall.  This will let you add drivers to the install without formatting.

Warning: you will/may have to reinstall software (due to the registry being reset), but all your data will be there.

For more info check out Microsoft KB 978788: [How to perform an in-place upgrade (reinstallation) of Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978788)

> An in-place upgrade is also named a repair installation. This operation reinstalls Windows XP to the same folder on your computer where it was originally installed.